# PHP SQL STMT SELECT multiple LIKE ? is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

```
SELECT * 
FROM datatable 
WHERE Name LIKE ? 
OR Code LIKE ? 
OR Date LIKE ? 
OR Inserter LIKE ? 
AND ID = '2'
```

> There is an error in php sql connection: 
>   *mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in*

Here is the error code, I am using

```
stmt->prepare, stmt->execute
```

and so on in php.

This works fine with just one LIKE ? (WHERE Name LIKE ? AND ID = '2').

How can I replace or solve this problem?

The real code

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($SearchQuery)) { 
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_term); 
    // Set parameters $param_term = '%' . $_POST["String"] . '%'; 
    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement 
    if ($stmt->execute()) { 
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Note that AND goes before OR. You probably want `WHERE (Name LIKE ? OR Code LIKE ? OR Date LIKE ? OR Inserter LIKE ?) AND ID = '2'`.

Comment: it's just a query statement, you'll need to add the code block related to the error

Comment: Nope. I did try this solution but it doesn't work. It has the same error.

Comment: ___Please read the error message___. This is saying that you are not passing the right number of values to match all the `?` **Show us your real code**. Do you actually pass any values to replace the `?` parameters

Comment: You use 4 placeholders. So you MUST give 4 parameters. Maybe the same parameter 4 times.

Comment: **After you fix this error**, you will also need to amend the WHERE clause and use brackets to ensure the correct application of the OR's ad AND's like `WHERE (Name LIKE ? OR Code LIKE ? OR Date LIKE ? OR Inserter LIKE ? )
AND ID = '2'`

Comment: **if ($stmt = $db->prepare($SearchQuery)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_term);
            // Set parameters
            $param_term = '%' . $_POST["String"] . '%';
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $result = $stmt->get_result();**

Comment: This would probably be readable if you edited it into the question

Comment: I mean I want to use **one search-word** and with it finding characters and strings in all *Name, Code, Date, Inserter* and so on. Just by one word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 `?` parameters and you are binding only one value

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param_term);
```

This should be

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $param_term,
                        $param_term,
                        $param_term,
                        $param_term);
```

so that each parameter `?` gets a value.

Also the query will need bracket to work correctly like this

```
WHERE (Name LIKE ? 
    OR Code LIKE ? 
    OR Date LIKE ? 
    OR Inserter LIKE ? ) 
AND ID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer strictly one copy of parameter into the query (assuming that you search the same pattern) you may use

```
SELECT * 
FROM datatable 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(CHAR(X), Name,Code,Date,Inserter) LIKE ? 
AND ID = '2'
```

where CHAR(x) is any char which cannot be found in a field or in a pattern.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I see that OP cannot understand the error message. But shown technique may solve his problem too... why not inform OP about it?

Comment: You make a good point, I didnt initially see this as a way of using only the one parameter :)